# Why doesn't Kelly Chambers send me a message after the suicide mission?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In my paragon career, I wanted to take Yeoman Kelly as my "romance". Fish feeding done, spent the night together, no other partners reached the point of romance action before the suicide mission, and she survived the suicide mission. I still did not get a message from her to invite her up to my cabin. Any ideas why?

As far as I can remember, two times she said that I have an unread message at my terminal, but I found nothing when I checked it. Maybe some bug?

Comment: Did you ask her if she was ok right after the suicide mission?

Comment: Yes. She told me how horrible the abduction was and had that drell memory flashback, Thane used to have. No other missions were done before the conversation.

Comment: Try checking the intercom to see if you can call her up anyways.

Answer (score 1):

There's a possibility it may not be available based on one of your dialogue choices during the suicide mission.  From the talk page on the Mass Effect Wiki:

> I think I figured out why it wasn't working in my case -- I replayed the suicide mission and the only thing that I know I changed was when you rescue the crew you get the choice to say "I wouldn't leave you behind" or "I didn't come for you", The first playthrough I chose the 2nd option and I think that pissed her off (was an accident, damn spacebar). After replaying and choosing the first option I got the email. --74.248.177.233 01:36, June 21, 2011 (UTC)
>
> > Had the same problem after my first run. What worked for me: After returning from the suicide mission (a second time), I first checked the private terminal in my cabin, so all old messages were marked as read. I then spoke to her first, comforting her. After that I made the tour around the CIC, spoke to Joker, Mordin, Jacob, returned to my terminal, she informed me about the message again - and there it was. --46.223.161.247 16:57, July 17, 2014 (UTC)

There are other possible fixes/issues discussed on the page, most notably under the heading of ["Frustrating"](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Kelly_Chambers#Frustrating).

Hopefully one of the solutions here can work for you.